# WCF Service not working in production environment

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis

I have a 3 tier distributed application - client GUI, WCF service hosted in IIS 7.5, and SQL DB.  Each tier resides on its own machine.  Everything works perfectly in my development environment but not in the production environment.  An object disposed exception is getting thrown in the WCF service.  We are using the exact same data and software, which I have double-checked and triple-checked.  The only thing I can think of that might be the problem is a difference in IIS configurations between the development and production environments.  I can see the application hitting the database, but the breakdown is occurring in the response back to the client from the WCF service.  What could cause the WCF service to work in the development environment but not the production environment?

Comment: Have you tried calling the wcf on dev and prod using a web service tester such as soapui. Then compare the request and the response between both environments. That will tell you if the wcf is configured properly and if the problem isbwith your client config. Also try turning on wcf tracing https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751526(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Also add details to the question what the exception says

Comment: Very helpful, Kyle!  The SoapUI looks promising.  I will get the details of the exception and post them when I get them.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I have tracing turned on and that is where I saw the object context disposed exception in the stack trace.  Also, we are using Entity Framework, if that matters.